# C#: Calling PostgreSql function with multiple output parameters

Tags: c#, postgresql, function, npgsql

I have a PostgreSQL function:

this function was borrowed from the npgsql [test](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/main/test/Npgsql.Tests/FunctionTests.cs#L164)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert1(IN param1 INT, OUT param2 text, INOUT param3 INT) RETURNS record AS
$$
BEGIN
    param2 = 'sometext';
    param3 = param1 + param3;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I am trying to call this function on the c# side as follows, but I get an error

```cs
using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(conStr))
{
    conn.Open();

    var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("public.insert1", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
    //NpgsqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).NpgsqlValue = 3;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter { ParameterName = "param2", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output, NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Text });
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter { ParameterName = "param3", Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput, Value = 4 });

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

> Npgsql.PostgresException: '42883: procedure public.insert1(param1 => integer, param2 => unknown, param3 => integer) does not exist

But if you call the same function in a different way, then it works without errors

```cs
 using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(con))
 {
     conn.Open();

     var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM public.insert1(:param1,  :param3)", conn);
     //NpgsqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).NpgsqlValue = 3;
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter { ParameterName = "param2", Direction = ParameterDirection.Output});
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter { ParameterName = "param3", Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput, Value = 4 });

     await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
 }
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

.net8;
PostgreSQL server version: 12.12;
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NodaTime: 8.0.0;

Comment: It's all in the docs https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#commandtypestoredprocedure also output parameters don't work like you think, see later in the docs